# Is there a pathological continuous function $\ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\ $ that is nowhere increasing or decreasing and has no local extrema?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, problem-solving, transfinite-induction

> Is there a pathological yet continuous function $\
> f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\ $ such that:
>
> For every $\ x\in\mathbb{R}\ $ and $\ \delta>0,\ \exists\ a,b,\ $ both
> in $\ (x,x+\delta),\ $ such that $\ f(a)<f(x)<f(b)\qquad (*)\quad ? $

This makes me think of [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) because it is nowhere increasing and nowhere decreasing. However, at some points of the Weierstrass function a local maximum is attained. Let $\ x\ $ be a local maximum. Then by definition of local maximum, $\ \exists\ \delta>0\ $ such that $\ a\in(x,x+\delta)\implies f(a)\leq f(x).\ $ Therefore the Weierstrass function does not satisfy $\ (*).$

Maybe such a function is well known? Or if not, I was wondering if we can construct such a function using [transfinite induction/recursion,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) although it might be difficult to prove that the function remains continuous in the limit case?

Or maybe there is some clever argument that any real function with the property $\ (*)\ $ cannot be continuous everywhere (in particular, the function cannot be continuous at $ x)$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that such a function exists.

Take any interval $[u, v]\subseteq\mathbb R, u<v$. As it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem), the (continuous) function $f$ reaches a maximum somewhere on $[u,v]$. If the maximum is reached in any point $x\in [u, v)$, then take $\delta=v-x$ and for all $b\in(x, x+\delta)$ you will have $f(b)\le f(x)$.

This means that the maximum is reached in $v$ only, i.e. $f(x)<f(v)$ for all $x\in[u,v)$. In particular, $f(u)<f(v)$. As $u<v$ were arbitrary, this then implies the $f$ is strictly increasing, which is impossible (it will be impossible to find $a$ for any $x, \delta$).

This contradiction proves that the function with properties given in your question does not exist.

Comment: This proof attempt was similar to my first proof attempt also, but I thought it fails for the following reason. You write,
"As $u<v$ were arbitrary, this then implies the $f$ is strictly increasing". Not necessarily, because for $f$ to be increasing at $v,$  you also need $f(w)>f(v)$ for all $w$ in some small interval close to $v...$

Comment: I don't understand @AdamRubinson's objection: strictly increasing *means* that for arbitrary $u<v$, $f(u)<f(v)$. But I have a different objection: you only get $f(x)\leq f(v)$, not strict $<$. But then the same argument with the minimum shows $f(x)\geq f(v)$. But then $f$ is constant on $[u,v]$, contradiction.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think you are right - I misunderstood Stinking Bishop's argument when I read it the first time round.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I actually get $f(x)<f(v)$ because otherwise $x$ would also be a point of maximum, smaller than $v$, and the argument that it is impossible would apply.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Ah, yes, good point.

Comment: @StinkingBishop I don't understand your last comment. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AdamRubinson if $f(v)=M$ is the maximum of $f$ on $[u,v]$, and, for some $x\in(u,v)$ we have $f(x)=f(v)$, then $f(x)=M$ - also the maximum, and as $x<v$ you can now take $\delta=v-x$ and conclude there aren't any $b\in(x,x+\delta)$ such that $M=f(x)<f(b)$,

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function without any local extrema. I'll prove that $f$ is strictly monotonic.

To see why, consider any $a < b$ in $\mathbb R$. The restricted function $f \mid [a,b]$ has a maximum and a minimum, by the Extreme Value Theorem. If any point of the open interval $(a,b)$ is an extremum of the restricted function, then the whole function $f$ has a local extremum, contradiction. Therefore, the *only* possible extrema for $f \mid [a,b]$ are $a$ and $b$, one of $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ is a maximum, and the other is a minimum, and they are not equal.

The argument in the previous paragraph holds for *all* choices of $a<b$ in $\mathbb R$. Using this, let me prove that $f$ is strictly monotonic. There might be a very slick argument at this point, but there is also a tedious proof by cases which I'll outline.

Pick an arbitrary pair $a<b$ to start, so either $f(a) < f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(b)$. I'll assume the $f(a)<f(b)$, and prove that for all $x<y \in \mathbb R$ we have $f(x)<f(y)$ (the other case, where $f(a)>f(b)$, follows just by switching the order).

First look at where $x$ is located with regard to $a$ and $b$. If $x<a<b$ then we must have $f(x)<f(a)$, because otherwise $f \mid [x,b]$ has a minimum value at some $c \in (x,b)$. If $a < x < b$ then $f(a) < f(x) < f(b)$ because otherwise $f \mid [a,b]$ has a minimum or maximum value at some $c \in (a,b)$. And if $a < b < x$ then $f(b) < f(x)$ because other wise $f \mid [a,x]$ has a maximum value at some $c \in (a,b)$.

Finally, look at where $x$ and $y$ are jointly located with regard to $a$ and $b$. By a similar case analysis, you can conclude that $f(x)<f(y)$.